# torch.cuda.is_available() = False JupyterNotebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cuda, anaconda, pytorch

У меня видеокарта nvidia 1060.
Стоит cuda 12.1.
В `Python` `torch.cuda.is_available() == True`
в JupyterNotebook `torch.cuda.is_available() == False`.

Естественно ставил с сайта pytorch.org и выбирал:

- Стабильная версия
- Linux
- Conda/Pip(для питона)
- cuda 11.8(если что, так можно-под 12.1 ставить библиотеку 11.8)

В питоне видит и работает с куда, в юпитере на отрез отказывается. В conda list видно что pytorch-cuda 11.8 стоит. Подскажите, как оживить cuda в анакоде для pytorch?

Comment: А юпитер из того же окружения запущен, где всё это стоит? P.S. Беглое гугление показало, что скорее всего дело в этом.

Comment: Да, юпитер из того же окружения запущен где всё стоит.